# How can I set the horizontal stackView according to the width of the first label

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, stackview

How can I align the stackview according to the content of the first label on storyboard ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the left label and then from size inspector change horizontal **Content Hugging Priority** = 1000

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the horizontal Content Hugging Priority of your left label has a higher value than the one on the right. The exact values don't matter, but the left one must be at least 1 higher than the one on the right. For example, use "Default High (750)" on the left and "Default Low (250)" on the right.